# Pull ID for MySQL INSERT from Name List Dropdown Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form where employees can input parts that they have ordered that will then show up on a list for all employees to view.  This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="../libraries/addpart.php">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <label for="job_id">Job #</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_id" placeholder="Job #">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <label for="part_needed">Part Needed</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="part_needed" placeholder="Part Needed">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <label for="date_ordered">Date Ordered</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_ordered">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <label for="vendor_id">Ordered From</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="vendor_id">
                        <option></option>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($vendors)) {
                            // Print out the contents of the entry
                            echo '<option>' . $row['vendor_name'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                    <label for="part_needed">ETA</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="part_eta">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5" name="addbutton">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

The form utilizes a dropdown that displays vendor names rather than their ID by querying from the `vendors` table.  When the form is submitted, I need the record to be inserted into the `ordered_parts` table with the vendor ID only, instead of the name.  This is my (rather messy) attempt at that:

```
/*
*   Get Vendor ID
*/
    $vendorname = $_POST['vendor_id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `vendors`
        WHERE vendor_name = $vendorname";
//Get results
    $vendorid = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);

    $job = $_POST['job_id'];
    $part = $_POST['part_needed'];
    $date = $_POST['date_ordered'];
    $vendor = $vendorid['vendor_id'];
    $eta = $_POST['part_eta'];


    $partorder = "INSERT INTO `ordered_parts`
            (job_id, part_needed, date_ordered, vendor_id, part_eta)
            VALUES
            ('$job', '$part', '$date', '$vendor', '$eta')";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $partorder);
    if ($result) {
        header('Location: ../views/ordered-parts.php');
    } else {
        echo("<br>Failed to add");
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use"

As you can probably tell, I've had no real experience with databases before this project.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Try to enclose your variable name with quotes. I am talking about _$vendorname_ in your first query.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should not trust user input and escape the _$vendorname_ value before using it in your query. For more information look for __SQL injection__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery would knock it out in a single statement; no need to query the `vendors` table first:

```
INSERT INTO `ordered_parts`
(job_id, part_needed, date_ordered, part_eta, vendor_id)
VALUES
('$job', '$part', '$date', '$eta', SELECT `vendor_id` FROM `vendors` WHERE `vendor_name` = '$vendor')
```

That being said, A.D. is correct -- building queries in this manner leaves you vulnerable to **SQL Injection**. You can take advantage of `mysqli`'s "parameterized" queries to avoid this, or use a string-escaping function.